# Uninstall Calibri font, installed from Windows' font directory

Tags: uninstall, fonts

I use a PC with both Ubuntu and Windows 7.

I tried to install the Calibri font in Ubuntu by opening the `calibri.ttf` file found under the Windows/Fonts directory using Font Viewer and clicked on the Install button.

Now I need to uninstall that font but I can't. Font Viewer shows me that the "Calibri Regular" font is installed but does not allow me to uninstall it. Font Manager does not show Calibri in the font list. Character Map does not show Calibri in the font list. Ubuntu Software Center and Synaptic don't find anything like "calibri".

There is also no calibri file under these directories:

- `/usr/share/fonts`
- `/usr/local/share/fonts`
- `~/.fonts`

The font is visible to LibreOffice, Chrome, Firefox.

EDITED

I executed `gedit /etc/fonts/fonts.conf` and this is part of the result:

```
«!-- Font directory list --»

<dir>/usr/share/fonts</dir>
<dir>/usr/local/share/fonts</dir>
<dir prefix="xdg">fonts</dir>
<!-- the following element will be removed in the future -->
<dir>~/.fonts</dir>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the font cache:

```
fc-cache -rv
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried now but it didn't work: I executed your command and restarted the computer, but Chrome still uses Calibri.

Comment: can you see what are locations of fonts.. execute this in run or console: `gedit /etc/fonts/fonts.conf` or `cat /etc/fonts/fonts.conf`